# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user for EVERY mysql command

Tags: mysql, linux

I encounter the error below no matter what mysql command I enter in my shell on my bluehost connected server.

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

The simplest command I have tried that nets this error is

```
mysql -u myuser -pMypass
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I am 100% sure the user and password are correct as I have tried several different users.
I have tried granting all permissions to each user.
I have tried executing as my root user. I have also tried with -e on a simply query.

Does anyone know if there is a global setting that is preventing my from even the simplest of commands?

I am getting access with PuTTy and can see/edit my files correctly.

**EDIT:::: SOLUTION:::: My password contained a '$' which needed to be escaped....**

Comment: `SELECT User, Host, Password FROM mysql.user;` as root. What do you get? Then, `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'myuser'@'localhost';`

Comment: This is a question you'll have to ask your host. We don't have the necessary information to troubleshoot it.

Comment: You'll need to contact bluehost support to fix this issue. Or try asking on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: @jchapa so after `SELECT User, Host, Password From mysql.user`i get a lot of output. Many things are set to FALSE... is there something I am looking for in particular (ssl is false)?

Comment: @jchapa also, the addition of `SHOW GRANTS FOR myuser@localhost` appears to be the same (as I am logged in as the root I presume)

Comment: Is this a shared mysql server? That can be your problem. Try this. `select User, Host, Password FROM mysql.user where User like '%myuser%';`

Comment: that command just returned the same info from the mysql.user with all the settings displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you ran

```
mysql -u myuser -p
```

and got this error

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

mysqld is expecting you to connect as `myuser@localhost`

Try creating `myuser@localhost`

```
CREATE USER myuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'passpass';
grant all privileges on *.* to myuser@localhost with grant option;
```

If you want to connect remotely, you must specify either the DNS name, the public IP, or 127.0.0.1 using TCP/IP:

```
mysql -u myuser -p -hmydb@mydomain.com
mysql -u myuser -p -h10.1.2.30
mysql -u myuser -p -h127.0.0.1 --protocol=TCP
```

Once you login, please run this

```
SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
```

[USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_user) reports how you attempted to authenticate in MySQL

[CURRENT_USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user) reports how you were allowed to authenticate in MySQL from the **mysql.user** table

This will give you a better view of how and why you were allowed to login to mysql. Why is this view important to know? It has to do with the user authentication ordering protocol.

Comment: the -h for host would be the DB name?

Comment: So it should look like --host=myuser@mydomain.com or --host=myuser@localhost ... both are giving me `ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host`

Comment: for everyone of these commands (Create user, Grant all privileges..) I just keep getting the `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.28, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1` followed by the list of properties.